# Haskell lifetime of memoized function bound to record instance

Tags: haskell, memoization

First of all, I'm a beginner in Haskell so be kind :)

Consider the following example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

data Item = Item {itemPrice :: Float, itemQuantity :: Float} deriving (Show, Eq)
data Order = Order {orderItems :: [Item]} deriving (Show, Eq)

itemTotal :: Item -> Float
itemTotal Item{..} = itemPrice * itemQuantity

orderTotal :: Order -> Float
orderTotal = sum . map itemTotal . orderItems
```

Is it possible to memoize the function `orderTotal` so it only execute once per "instance" of an `Order` record and, this is the tricky part, the cache entry bound to this instance is eliminated once this order is garbage collected? In other words, I don't want to have a cache that keeps growing forever.

**Edit after comments:**

Indeed, in this simple example the overhead of memoization probably doesn't pay off. But you can imagine a scenario where we have a complex graph of values (e.g. order, order items, products, client...) and lots of derived properties that operate on these values (like the orderTotal above). If we create a field for the order total, instead of using a function to compute it, we have to be very careful to not end up with an inconsistent order.

Wouldn't be nice if we can express these data interdependencies declaratively (using functions instead of fields) and delegate the job to optimize these calculations to the compiler? I believe that in a pure language like Haskell this would be possible, although I lack the knowledge to do that.

To illustrate what I'm trying to say, look at this code (in Python):

```py
def memoized(function):
    function_name = function.__name__

    def wrapped(self):
        try:
            result = self._cache[function_name]
        except KeyError:
            result = self._cache[function_name] = function(self)
        return result

    return property(wrapped)


class Item:
    def __init__(self, price, quantity):
        self._price = price
        self._quantity = quantity
        self._cache = {}

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self._price

    @property
    def quantity(self):
        return self._quantity

    @memoized
    def total(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

The class `Item` is immutable (kind of), so we know that each derived property can be computed only once per instance. That's exactly what the `memoized` function does. Besides that, the cache lives inside the instance itself (`self._cache`), so it will be garbage collected with it.

What I'm looking for is to achieve a similar thing in Haskell.

Comment: I suspect the overhead of tracking live `Order` values, along the cache of their `orderTotal` values, would be greater than recomputing the value.

Comment: Don't worry about memoizing a function until you can demonstrate that the time spend in `orderTotal` is actually a problem.

Comment: Even assuming memoization helps here, you can't achieve what you want by only modifying `orderTotal`. That, at best, can create a cache which lasts for the whole program, or create a "cache" every single call (useless). You need instead to modify where `orderTotal` is called, so that, at the call point, you can create a cache, use it several times, and then know it is time to throw it away.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited the question with more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relatively simple way of memoizing a calculation on a value of a particular type is to bring the calculated result into the data type and use a smart constructor.  That is, write the `Order` data type as:

```
data Order = Order
  { orderItems :: [Item]
  , orderTotal :: Float
  } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Note that the `orderTotal` field replaces your function of the same name.  Then, construct orders using the smart constructor:

```
order :: [Item] -> Order
order itms = Order itms (sum . map itemTotal $ itms)
```

Because of lazy evaluation, the `orderTotal` field will be calculated only the first time it's needed with the value cached thereafter.  When the `Order` is garbage collected, obviously the `orderTotal` will be garbage collected at the same time.

Some people would pack this into a module and export only the smart constructor `order` instead of the usual constructor `Order` to ensure that an order with an inconsistent `orderTotal` could never be created.  I worry about these people.  How do they get through their daily lives knowing that they might double-cross themselves at any moment?  Anyway, it's an available option for the truly paranoid.

Comment: Don't know if your answer is correct, but your POV on certain people advocating certain programming styles - who absolutely exist! - is spot on...

Comment: This is more about deferring the computation than memoizing it. Each `Order`'s total is computed on demand, but if two `Order`s have the same items, you still compute the sum twice.

Comment: @kabuhr I really liked your solution, it's simple and elegant. I would never thought that laziness could help here. The only downside I see so far is, if the Order type has lots of attributes, it's difficult to know which parameter is what in the smart constructor signature because they are not named. But I can live with that and I will accept your answer. Thank you very much.